# Windows terminal is missing after reboot

Tags: reboot, windows-store, windows-terminal

I'm using Windows Terminal in my VDI environment(via Citrix)

If I reboot my VDI environment Windows terminal is not available. Again I've to visit Windows Store and re-install.

After that my settings and configurations are remains.(Ex: Oh-my-posh is still there)

Why it's happening and how to avoid this?

Comment: Are you an Administrator? The fact you reboot and the configuration resets suggests it’s not part of the baseline image

Comment: Yes I'm an Admin

Comment: @iamramanavenkat You mention that other *"settings and configuration"* are still there, but what about other Store applications?  For instance, if you install Spotify from the Store (just as a test; it could be any app), is it still there after reboot?  This isn't the first time I've seen a question about disappearing Store apps after reboot.  But sadly I've never seen a solution posted yet.  Just want to know if we're talking about "Disappearing Windows Terminal" or "Disappearing Store Apps" in general.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is. I've checked by installing Spotify app from Microsoft Store. After rebooting it's missing :(